# Replacing files in jar by files in folder

Tags: java, jar

I have a directory, update, with the same structure as a JAR file Application.jar. Now I want to (programmatically) replace all files in Application.jar with the files in the update folder. Lets say I have the following structure for both directory and jar file:

```
Application.jar / update
    - TestDir
        - text2.txt
    - text1.txt
```

When using `jar uf Application.jar update/TestDir/text2.txt` it creates a new directory in Application.jar - update - and it's going to be added all from there, even worse when using absolute paths (Creating the whole C:\ structure inside the jar file). How can I preserve the structure, is there some way to mark pathToUpdate\update as a root? I know there's the -C parameter, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. First change the working directory to `update` so that the relative path to the 'update' file matches what you want in the jar:

   ```
   cd update
   jar uf ../Application.jar TestDir/text2.txt
   ```
2. use the -C option:

   ```
   jar uf Application.jar -C update TestDir/text2.txt
   ```

It's possible the -C option requires that you do: `jar Application.jar -C update update/TestDir/text2.txt`.

In general, I advise the first option; the second gets tricky once you start using e.g. `*` and the like.